# Cross-domain Javascript - Pull Meta Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a Meteor.js app and one of the things I'd like to do is pull the title and meta description tags from a saved page. I'm using [this cross domain program](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) and have half of the code working.

Here's the excerpt; it takes the value given in a form tagged "url" and runs the code:

```
$.get(url, function(response){
      if ((suggestedTitle=((/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(response.responseText))) != null){
          $('#title').val(suggestedTitle[1]);
      }else{
          $('#title').val(url);
      }
      if ((suggestedDesc=($('meta[name=description]').attr('content'))) != undefined){
        $('#desc').val(suggestedDesc[1]);
      }else{
        $('#desc').val('Description for this page cannot be found.');
      }
   });
```

I recognize it's not best practice to use regular expressions to parse HTML (open to suggestions on an alternative but I haven't looked into it too carefully) but that aside, this script successfully pulls the title from the URL or returns the web address if it can't be found, but the description fails and just returns the fallback text. Would appreciate some help, thanks :)

Comment: Use `$(response.responseText).find('meta[name="description"]')` or whatever. Without the `$(response.responseText)` part, you aren't looking at the response - you'd be looking at the current page. Since you already know using Regex isn't a good way to parse HTML, let jQuery do it the right way; then just traverse that DOM object

Comment: I have tried this but for some reason still can't get it to work... it tells me the response is undefined. I added a meta description to the page I'm on to see if it would try to pull that instead... do you have a longer code sample?

Comment: I just added an answer that seems to work. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using regex or jQuery to parse the response, use DOM methods to go through the response text. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    type: "GET",
    async: true
}).done(function (response) {
    var div = document.createElement("div"),
        responseText = response.results[0],
        title, metas, meta, name, description, i;
    div.innerHTML = responseText;
    title = div.getElementsByTagName("title");
    title = title.length ? title[0].innerHTML : undefined;
    metas = div.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        name = metas[i].getAttribute("name");
        if (name === "description") {
            meta = metas[i];
            description = meta.getAttribute("content");
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log("Title:", title);
    console.log("Description:", description);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("AJAX ERROR:", textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KLdsG/3/

I put the plugin you provided at the top (it's minified so it will fit and you can still see your own code.

Obviously, this uses `http://www.google.com`, but you should be able to put any URL in and it work the same. Also, you can put this into a reusable function - I just wanted to show an example. I would assume it works the same with `$.get()` instead of `$.ajax()`.

You can't directly use `response.responseText`, because the item returned is an object consisting of a few things. To get the HTML, you can use `response.results[0]`. `response.results` is obviously an array, and I'm not sure what else could be in there (like in index 1, 2, 3, etc.).

And I found weird things happening when I tried using `$(response.results[0])`, so I just stuck with normal DOM manipulation.